# csrf_token verification with Javascript XMLHttpRequest() (403 Forbidden)

Tags: javascript, django, xmlhttprequest, django-csrf

i am trying to send a XMLHttpRequest() post request to the Django Server but it shows 403 Forbidden,
after searching i found that it is due to CSRF verification , after seeing lot of similar content still i am unable to figure out how to implement csrf in XMLHttpRequest
i am including the js snippet that i am using

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    document.addEventListener('click',event => {
        if (event.target.id === "add-cart-button")
        {   event.preventDefault();
            const add_cart_button_id = event.target.dataset.pid
            const item_class = event.target.dataset.type
            const item_name = event.target.dataset.item
            const size_chooser = `#${item_class}-size-${add_cart_button_id}`
            var sel = document.querySelector(size_chooser)
            const size = sel.value          
            const quantity_chooser = `#${item_class}-quantity-${add_cart_button_id}`
            const quantity = document.querySelector(quantity_chooser).value

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest()          
            request.open('POST','/addcart')

            request.onload = () => {
                const data = request.responseText
            }

            var data = new FormData()
            data.append('iten_class',item_class)
            data.append('item_name',item_name)
            data.append('size',size)
            data.append('quantity',quantity)
            request.send(data)

        }
    })

})
```

i am sending this request to /addcart route of django server

```
def addcart(request):
    return JsonResponse({'status':True})
```

which just returns this status

can anyone help me in csrf verification

Comment: Usually the token is passed as a request header. You've to find the correct token from the page and then set is as a header with a correct name to the XHR.

Comment: in order to put csrf token in webpage i have to first retrive it from the server how can i do that or i just have to write {% csrf_token %} as we do with forms ?

Comment: Most likely reading the [Django documentation about its CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#ajax) answers the question best.

Comment: the documentation is given in reference with jQuery and i am not familiar with jQuery

Comment: With the provided information of how have you set the CSRF protection, it's impossible to answer the question. In a general case (the token is placed on the page using `{% csrf_token %}`) you read it by `token = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value`, and then (naming by your own code) you set the header: `request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', token);`. The header must be set after opening the request, and before sending it.

Comment: okay let me give a try of whatever you said hope that it will work now

Comment: Oh thanks it is working :)

Comment: Yes i was reading the token by enclosing it in a div and reading it by div's id innerHTML property but that was not working.